# azure-aks docker container python-django url not working

Tags: docker, azure-aks

I have created Docker that has debian + python-django that runs on 8000 port.  But after deploying into azure-aks, url path is not working under 8000 port.  Keeping important detials below.

Step 1:

```
Dockerfile :
 EXPOSE 8000

 RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 manage.py migrate
 CMD [ "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Step 2:
After building docker image, pushing it to azure registry.

Step 3:
myfile.yaml :  this is to deploy azure registry file into aks cluster.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myops
spec:
 replicas: 1
selector:
 matchLabels:
   app: myops
template:
 metadata:
   labels:
     app: myops
 spec:
   containers:
   - name: myops
     image: quantumregistry.azurecr.io/myops:v1.0
     ports:
     - containerPort: 8000
 ---
 # [START service]
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: myops-python
 spec:
   type: LoadBalancer
   ports:
   - port: 8000
     targetPort: 8888
   selector:
     app: myops
 # [END service]
```

Deploy into aks : kubectl apply -f myops.yaml

Step 4: check sevice

```
kubectl get service  myops-python --watch
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
myops-python   LoadBalancer   <cluster-ip>   <external-ip>   8000:30778/TCP   37m
```

Note: i have masked IP to not to expose to public.

step 5: i see container is running alright

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
myops-5bbd459745-cz2vc                1/1     Running            0          19m
```

step 6: I see container log and it shows that python is running under host 0.0.0.0:8000 port.

```
 kubectl logs -f myops-5bbd459745-cz2vc
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

WARNING:param.main: pandas could not register all extension types imports failed with the following error: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/generic.py)
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 19, 2021 - 06:47:57
Django version 3.2.5, using settings 'myops_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

The issue is that when I open this in browser http://:8000/myops_app, it is not working and timing out.

Answer (score 1):

The Service `myops-python` is set up to receive requests on port 8000 but then it will send the request to the pod on target port 8888.

> ```
>   ports:
>   - port: 8000
>     targetPort: 8888
> ```

The container `myops` in the Pod `myops`, however, is not listening on port 8888. Rather it is listening on port 8000.

> Dockerfile:
>
> ```
> EXPOSE 8000
> RUN /usr/local/bin/python3 manage.py migrate CMD [ "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
> ```

Please set `spec.ports[0].targetPort` to `8000` manually or remove `targetPort` from `spec.ports[0]` in the Service `myops-python`. By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field. For more information please see [Defining a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service).

**Tip:** You can use `kubectl edit service <service-name> -n <namepsace>` to edit your Service manifest.